# Fastest way to get dynamically updated HTML content from website?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dynamic-html

I want to scrape a stocks website and get the prices using selenium. I can't use normal HTML requests as the HTML is dynamic. 
I am using the headless selenium webdriver to get the data, but it takes around 30 seconds for each request. 
Is there a faster way to get the dynamic HTML?

Comment: To render a whole dynamic website a browser is necessary and it takes time. Selenium is doing nothing else. So it depends on the internet speed, the performance of your computer and the browser you are using for selenium.

Comment: Did  you check if that website do not offer an API? If yes, it will be faster than trying to scrape it. Also, if only one page take 30 scd to load, big chance are you can't do much to reduce that loading time.

Comment: If you add the website, we can see if we can help you find faster ways to do it.

Comment: The base website is "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/ " and the program adds each stock's symbol to the end of the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you are stuck with Selenium's wait-time with rendering**

Dynamic HTML requires a full browser. There is not much negotiating with that. If your pages are separate and distinct, i.e. you are scraping stocks.com/oilandgas as well as stocks.com/agriculture, there is a possible way to speed things up.

The one option you might have is to create a separate thread for each Selenium Webdriver instance and have both web pages scraped at the same time by two different Selenium Webdrivers.

The caveat to that is that it will only speed things up if the bottleneck (what is causing the slowness) is the rendering of the website.

<strike>If it is the internet speed, the processing power of your computer, or the server speed of the website, this would not improve things.</strike>

Actually, Daniel Farrell below suggests that it would improve the networking speed. You may want to give this a shot.

Comment: Network latency is usually mitigated by parallelism even if networking isn't the bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll probably just use an API to get the stock prices.

Comment: Ya, an API really would be the way to go if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

That site is getting data from a XHR

[image: network tab]

so you could just load that with requests and json.loads which is way faster already.

As far as getting updated HTML faster than polling, there are some frameworks (puppeteer) that can send update events from the browser to the main script but AFAIK there's no way to do it in Python.

Answer (score 1):

There are two APIs you can use to get summary info and the company profile based on ticker. You can use faster requests and Session for efficiency to make requests for this info.

```
import requests

tickers = ['FB']
results = {}

with requests.Session() as s:
    for ticker in tickers:
        results[ticker] = {}
        r = s.get(f'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/{ticker}/summary?assetclass=stocks').json()
        results[ticker]['summary'] = r
        r = s.get(f'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/{ticker}/company-profile').json()
        results[ticker]['profile'] = r
```